# Forward Domain to Subdomain in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dns

I would like to forward a domain to a particular subdomain (blog1.com --> blog1.example.com).

I have a Rails app that has a couple of subdomains. I'm using constraints to manage the subdomain routes like this:

```
#routes.rb

constraints :subdomain => "blog1" do
  root :to => "blog1#index"
end

constraints :subdomain => "blog2" do
  root :to => "blog2#index"
end
```

I've set up Heroku with a domain like example.com and added a wildcard domain through Heroku. The subdomains work great. I can get blog1.example.com without any issue.

I also added a cname (alias with dnsimple.com) from blog1.com --> blog1.example.com and added blog1.com as a domain on heroku. But blog1.com doesn't catch the subdomain route. Any suggestions to get the domain to respond?

Answer (score 0):

i am not a dns expert, but i guess that you actually need to redirect in order for that to work.

otherwise you reach one domain through the other, but this is transparent for the server and the server is what matters in your case.

Comment: I don't think a redirect would work. With a redirect the url would show the subdomain. I would like to use the primary domain (blog1.com) as the domain, but have it display the content from blog1.example.com. Similar to how tumblr uses custom domains.